# How to measure exterior track style storm windows, for replacement?

Tags: windows, replacement

I need to replace my storm windows. They are old 3-track windows. The thing is I don;t know how to measure them, should I measure the entire assembly from edge to edge, or should I measure the actual window pane assembly, or should I measure the main window opening?

Here is a picture of the actual windows.[image: Storm Windows]